# Unable to acquire multiprocessing.lock() in custom log handler

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, error-handling, multiprocessing

I have the code here: https://gist.github.com/ttback/7469849
I attempt to acquire a multiprocessing.lock() in order to allow multiple processes to log errors into a errorList variable so that I could have sensible error log output after all the parallel processes are ran. But the multiprocessing.Lock().acquire() seems to block even when I try a test call with logger.error("Fake Error")  (no multiprocessing involved at that point)
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: the python logging module is already thread-safe. There should be no reason for you to ask for a lock within your handler. Can you explain further why you think you need to do this, and perhaps to what you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @VooDooNOFX That's what I thought before, but it doesn't seem to work when multiple processes access the logger. The list variable had jumboed results and after tracing it closely, it looks like each list output at one point all had one element in them. The result is random as well, meaning the default locking does not work with multiple processes. (They worked with threading) I do not exactly know why it didn't work as it should, but some locking is needed to make the log handler handle emit calls from multiple processes